# How do I use HTTParty methods in a subclass?

Tags: ruby, httparty

I'm trying to write an API wrapper in Ruby and am stumped on how I can call HTTParty methods from a subclass.

I want the user to create a connection to the API and then be able to query results from subclasses.

```
module ApiWrapper
  class Connection
    include HTTParty
    base_uri '...'

    def initialize( u, p )
      ...
    end

    def contacts
      ApiWrapper::Contact
    end
  end
end

module ApiWrapper
  class Contact
    def all
      # issue httparty get request here that is created from the Connection class
    end
  end
end


## The user would do this
conn = ApiWrapper::Connection.new( 'username', 'password' )
contacts = conn.contacts.all
```

Answer (score 3):

`all()` is an instance method, not a class method, but you are calling it like a class method. Try it like this:

```
module ApiWrapper
  class Contact
    def self.all
      # issue httparty get request here that is created from the Connection class
    end
  end
end
```